# How to parse entire dataframe for key word in R

Tags: r, dataframe, search

```
  V16      V17      V18
nm:i:18  ms:i:40  as:i:40
ms:i:30  as:i:25  nn:i:0
ms:i:40  as:i:40  nn:i:0
```

I have three main columns which contain values that are tagged using either `ms`, `as`, or `nn`. I want to be able to get for each row anything containing `ms` and compare it to `as`.

I tried `grepl`, `subset`, and `which`. Not sure whats the best way to compare these?

For example:

```
  V17     V18
ms:i:40 as:i:40
```

OR

```
  V16     V17
ms:i:30 as:i:25
```

Expected (create new columns with the values sorted):

```
  V19      V20
ms:i:40  as:i:40
ms:i:30  as:i:25  
ms:i:40  as:i:40
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @akrun I want to create a new data frame with new columns of ms and as so I can view view differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would think maybe a `dplyr` solution would be most effective:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, 
                 V16 = c("nm:i:18", "ms:i:30", "ms:i:40"), 
                 V17 = c("ms:i:40", "as:i:25", "as:i:40"), 
                 V18 = c("as:i:40", "nn:i:0", "nn:i:0"))

df %>% 
gather(id, var, V16:V18) %>% 
filter(grepl("ms|as", var)) %>% 
mutate(newID = ifelse(grepl("ms", var), "V19", "V20")) %>% 
dplyr::select(-id) %>% 
spread(newID, var)

  ID     V19     V20
1  1 ms:i:40 as:i:40
2  2 ms:i:30 as:i:25
3  3 ms:i:40 as:i:40
```